# How to compare two models with and without restricted cubic spline by likelihood test? #mice #survival # rms

Tags: r, cox-model, splines, rms, mice

I’m new to using multiple imputations and I would like an opinion on using it with survival analysis in R.

**I would like to perform a multiple imputation on data with missing values (mice package) and perform a survival time analysis (coxph). I want to perform a likelihood ratio test for a model with a spline(rms::rcs) in the covariates and a model without.**

In this link (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.13.0/topics/pool.compare), it seems that 'glm / lm' models can be compared by using pool.compare (or D1/D3 function) corporated in the "mice" package.

```
#mice::nhanes2
#load package and data  
library(survival)
library(mice)
library(tidyverse)

data(nhanes2) 
set.seed(42)

#Create dummy data /  "time to death" and "death" category to apply coxph 
time_death<- as.integer(runif(nrow(nhanes2), min = 100, max = 1000))
death  <- as.integer((runif(nrow(nhanes2), min = 0, max = 2)))
nhanes2 <- nhanes2 %>% mutate(death=death , time_death=time_death)


#-----------------
# mice
imp <- mice(nhanes2, m = 10, seed = 1, print = FALSE)

# produce the models to compare, a full model and
# an intercept only restricted model  
fit.imputed.full <- with(imp, lm(bmi ~ age + chl))
fit.imputed.res <- with(imp, lm(bmi ~ 1))  

# compare models using pool.compare()
pooled.comparison <- pool.compare(fit.imputed.full, fit.imputed.res) #Same to D1 or D3

#pooled.comparison <- D1(fit.imputed.full, fit.imputed.res)
pooled.comparison$pvalue  #<-- success
```

For survival time analysis, we have confirmed that "coxph function" can do the similar analysis.

```
#-------------------
# produce the cox proportional hazard models (after mice) to compare, a full model and control
fit.imputed.full_coxph <- with(imp, coxph(Surv(time_death,death)~ bmi + age + hyp+ chl))
fit.imputed.full_ctrl <- with(imp, coxph(Surv(time_death,death)~ bmi + chl))

pooled.comparison <- pool.compare(fit.imputed.full_coxph, fit.imputed.full_ctrl) #Same to D1 or D3
pooled.comparison$pvalue #<-success
```

**But for models with restricted cubic spline, is it not possible to compare between the two models (model with rcs and without rcs)?**

```
#Can we apply restricted cubic spline (rcs) to pool.compare (D1)??
# produce the cox proportional hazard models (after mice) to compare, a full model and control
fit.imputed.full_coxph_rcs <- with(imp, rms::cph(Surv(time_death,death)~ bmi + age + hyp+ chl))
fit.imputed.full_ctrl_rcs <- with(imp, rms::cph(Surv(time_death,death)~ rcs(bmi,k=3) + chl))

ddist <- datadist(nhanes2)
options(datadist='ddist')

pooled.comparison <- pool.compare(fit.imputed.full_coxph_rcs, fit.imputed.full_ctrl_rcs) #Same to D1 or D3
```

**Problem**

```
Error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Please see attached code.
Thank you very much for your cooperation.
Could you provide us with the best solution or suggestions?

Comment: Note that your `fit.imputed.full_coxph_rcs` and `fit.imputed.full_ctrl_rcs` aren't nested, as the former includes predictors not in the second while the second includes `rcs()` terms not in the first. I suspect that  `pool.compare()` requires nested models, like those in your first 2 examples, where the predictors in one model are a subset of those in the other.

Comment: @EdM thank you for your answering and sincere reply.

I understand the nested data in the model plays an important role to 'pool.compare'.
However, could we perform to make nested data in `rcs()`?

Do you know the examples?

Answer (score 1):

Some of this question seems to be specific to software implementation, which is [off-topic on this site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but there are some statistical issues that should be addressed.

First, the attempt to compare `fit.imputed.full_coxph_rcs` and `fit.imputed.full_ctrl_rcs` via a likelihood-ratio test, as shown in the question, isn't valid. Such tests can only done on nested models in which the predictors of one model form a subset of the other model. That's not the case for those two models as shown, as the former includes predictors not in the second while the second includes `rcs()` terms not in the first. I can't say for sure that explains the error message, but check with truly nested models first in which the only difference in predictors has to do with `rcs()` terms.

Second, it's not clear that the `pool.compare()` function is the best way to do such a likelihood-ratio test. According to the [documentation you cite](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.13.0/topics/pool.compare), the function has been deprecated in favor of a `D3()` function that implements the [methods for such tests described by Van Buuren](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-multiparameter.html#sec:likelihoodratio). Combining likelihood-ratio tests among multiply imputed data sets requires some care.

Third, you might consider doing Wald tests on the `rcs()` terms instead. In the `rms` package many tests are implemented as Wald tests on the coefficient estimates and their covariances. In particular, that is how `anova()` works on `cph` objects; if such a model includes `rcs()` terms, the test for its nonlinear terms is a Wald test. Some notes in your code suggest that you have specified a `D1()`-type function for the model comparison. That's a Wald test, not a likelihood-ratio test.

A few hints for getting beyond this problem.

First, once the `rms` package is loaded the `rcs()` function should be accessible to the standard `coxph()` function. See if that works.

Second, the `rms` package inherits its own imputation function, `aregImpute()`, from the `Hmisc` package. That's designed to work directly with `rms` functions like `cph()`. You could thus consider working completely within the `rms` package for this.

Third, the functions used by the `mice` package can be quite picky about the way that model objects are constructed. Make sure to read the documentation very carefully; make sure that all required packages are installed and working properly and that the model objects you feed to functions in `mice` have the values and corresponding names that the functions are looking for. This could be something as simple as your code setting the `datadist` option after you did the `cph()` models; perhaps without the `datadist` set first the `cph` objects lack some critical value needed to work with `mice`.

Finally, think about why you really need to do this comparison. If you have a large enough data set and the cubic spline fits OK, how important is it to see if that does any better than a simple linear fit?

Comment: Thank you for your sincere reply!  Your reply helps me lots!