# How to perform Restricted cubic spline (Cox adjusted) after multiple imputation with mice?

Tags: cox-model, splines, multiple-imputation, cubic

Hello I would like to perform restricted cubic spline (Cox adjusted) after multiple imputation with mice.I use **rms** package. but after imputation when I use the function `datadist` I get this message **(Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic.)**
I'm using the following code.

## Multiple imputation

```
`Mydata<- mice::mice(cohort,seed = 123, print = FALSE,m=5)
```

**# Converting data and performing restricted cubic spline**

```
d<-datadist(Mydata)
options(datadist="d")
k<-with(Mydata,quantile(tg,c(.05,0.25,0.75,0.95)))
fit<- cph(Surv(time, cvd) ~ rcs(tg, k)+covariates, data=Mydata)
myplot <- Predict(fit,tg, ref.zero = TRUE, fun=exp)

ggplot(dataplot,aes(tg, yhat)) +  geom_line(colour="blue", linetype="solid", size=1)+geom_hline(yintercept =1, linetype="dashed")`
```

Any guidance.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to say more about just where in the process the challenge arises, as there are several ways things could go awry. Does [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/46333/28500) help? Or [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/545715/28500)?

Comment: If I recall, the `fit.mult.impute` function also accepts output from `{mice}`.  Start there.

Comment: @DemetriPananos, Thank you for your suggestion it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `datadist()` expects as its argument:

> a list of variable names, separated by commas, a **single** data frame, or a fit with Design information. (From help page; emphasis added.)

You provided it with what's effectively a list of 5 data frames, one per imputation. So it didn't know what to do.*

A `datadist` object provides useful choices for later display of model results. You don't *need* to use `datadist` to fit the model or to display results with `Predict()`. As the help page for `Predict()` says, there's an alternative:

> For variables not described using `datadist`, you must specify explicit ranges and adjustment settings for predictors that were in the model.

What might be simpler would be to use `datadist()` on *one* of the imputed data sets. That should allow you to use the convenient summaries of model results like those that `Predict()` provides.

---

*I suspect that you have a similar problem with the way that you are calling `cph()` on the imputed data sets. I understand that you need to call the `fit.mult.impute()` function with `fitter=cph`, as Demetri Pananos indicates in a comment, to get the proper results based on Rubin's rules.

Comment: I am sorry for my late reply, thank you for your reply your explanation was helpful. I found a solution that is, I have to use datadist before multiple imputation by mice then I used fit.mult.impute() with fitter=cph. However, I found that ‘predict ‘returns very few values.

Comment: @Bkry there's a difference between the generic `predict()` as it works on particular modeling objects and the `Predict()` function in `rms`.  Read the documentations carefully. You might need to provide a set of `newdata` values in some cases.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help I could perform the analysis. I read the documentation and understood the difference.